# Can these to_csv functions be written such that they load data from dataframe to csv concurrently?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

```
if len(isd) != 0:
    isd.to_csv("Issuedate.csv")
if len(ind) != 0:
    ind.to_csv("Inceptiondatecsv")
if len(exd) != 0:
    exd.to_csv("Expirydate.csv")
if len(psd) != 0:
    psd.to_csv("policystatedate.csv")
if len(visd) != 0:
    visd.to_csv("vehicleissuedate.csv")
if len(vind) != 0:
    vind.to_csv("vehicleinceptiondate.csv")
if len(vexd) != 0:
    vexd.to_csv("vehicleexpirydate.csv")
if len(sd) != 0:
    sd.to_csv("statusdate.csv")
if len(ise) != 0:
    ise.to_csv("istemarhexpiry.csv")
if len(idb) != 0:
    idb.to_csv("insureddateofbirth.csv")
if len(mdd) != 0:
    mdd.to_csv("maindriverdob.csv")
if len(add) != 0:
    add.to_csv("adddriverdob.csv")
```

Can These can be sped up using multithreading or multiprocessing. I'm pretty new to python and want to load data to csv file concurrently.

Comment: How big are the dataframes? Are you ok with compromising a much higher memory usage for speed here?

Comment: If there is no other way then yes i can compromise.

Comment: You would make a list of your data frames, then with `mp.pool`, apply a mapping function that executes the save code and the `len` logic.

Comment: @ifly6: Will multiprocessing be more beneficial than multithreading?

Comment: Multiprocessing is normally the way concurrency is implemented in Python due to the GIL.

Comment: I'm not familiar with multiprocessing in python can you provide a slight overview or resource on how it can be implemented to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues. I could not find any documentation as to whether the `to_csv` dataframe method releases the GIL. If we knew that it did, then we would want to use a multithreading pool since we would still get parallel processing and we would not suffer the overhead resulting from passing a (large?) dataframe from the main process's address space to the pool's child process's address space (via *pickle*). But regardless of whether we are using multithreading or multiprocessing, you would be attempting to do multiple file creations in parallel. Depending on whether you have a solid state drive or not and what its characteristics are, this could be counterproductive due to excessive head movement and you only have a certain limited bandwidth for doing I/O operations. So assuming we have to do the processing with the more costly multiprocessing pool, it is not at all clear how much performance will be improved if at all.

But this is how you might do it (function `main1`). I have also added function `main2` which does the same processing serially and I compare both times. I only have two trivial dataframes and a non-solid state drive, so the resulting numbers may be quite different from your case:

```py
def save_df(df, csv_name):
    df.to_csv(csv_name)


def main1():
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Jane'],
        'Age': [10, 20, 30, 39],
        'Sex': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F']
    })

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
        'Age': [10, 20, 30],
        'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F']
    })

    # Somehow we have a list of tuples consisting of dataframe, csv-name pairs
    dfs = [(df1, 'df1.csv'), (df2, 'df2.csv')]

    # Filter these so that we do not unproductively submit 0-length dataframes:
    filtered_dfs = list(filter(lambda t: len(t[0]), dfs))
    pool_size = min(len(filtered_dfs), cpu_count())
    t = time.time()
    with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        pool.starmap(save_df, filtered_dfs)
    print(time.time() - t)

def main2():
    import time
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Jane'],
        'Age': [10, 20, 30, 39],
        'Sex': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F']
    })

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
        'Age': [10, 20, 30],
        'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F']
    })

    # Somehow we have a list of tuples consisting of dataframe, csv-name pairs
    dfs = [(df1, 'df1.csv'), (df2, 'df2.csv')]

    # Filter these so that we do not unproductively submit 0-length dataframes:
    filtered_dfs = list(filter(lambda t: len(t[0]), dfs))
    t = time.time()
    for df, csv in filtered_dfs:
        save_df(df, csv)
    print(time.time() - t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main1()
    main2()
```

Prints:

```None
0.6069865226745605
0.002997159957885742
```

Serial processing is much more performant due to the overhead due to our using multiprocessing compared with the trivialness the `save_df` worker function for such small dataframes. As the work required to be done by `save_df` increases with larger dataframes, then multiprocessing *might* start looking better.

Comment: Wouldn't the overhead to send the data to another process increase as well when you are using larger dataframes? I don't think multiprocessing will *ever* help in this case, unless you create the dataframes inside different processes in the start itself, and then naturally export them to csv without ever having to send them to different processes.

Comment: @Charchit Absolutely, the data-passing overhead will increase with larger dataframes, but so will the CPU usage of `save_df`. There is a fixed overhead in doing multiprocessing that I think dominated the above benchmark, which did not represent the OP's actual case. The question is whether that fixed overhead becomes negligible as the worker function is passed more data and uses more CPU and what is gained by running the worker function in parallel compensates for the cost of the data being passed. I am doubtful, too, but I just don't know the answer for sure until somebody tries.